# OpenPyxl load_workbook save

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a problem with the function "save" from load_workbook from openpyxl. Actually I probably don't correctly use it. But it will be really great if you tell me how to use it.

The problem is the following: 
First I do an instantiation of a `"load_workbook"` object

```
self.load_wb = load_workbook(self.report_path)
```

and then I execute several of my own methods that I developed which are associated to my object symbolised above by `"self"`. Each of this methods are finish by the `"save"` methods.

```
self.load_wb.save(self.report_path)
```

When the script is finish. I open my excel file and there is an error... Nevertheless Excel takes into account the error and there is no apparent problems... But this not good for me...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9p3O.png)

Nevertheless, when I used only one time the "save" method, the error doesn't appear when I open my excel file.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: put the error text here

Comment: and use a minimal code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what is the extension of the file you're reading?

Comment: This is an xlsx file

Comment: @Leo *"when I used only one time the "save" method, the error doesn't appear "*: The `save(...` function is intended to use **only one time** at the end.

Comment: Ok I ve done something better ! :D I save only one time the file. :D